# How to set properly Curl options to upload multipart file to google Drive using Filemaker 16-18

Tags: api, curl, integration, filemaker

Google Documentation explains that the call should include:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_ENTIRE_REQUEST_BODY]

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "myObject"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[JPEG_DATA]
--foo_bar_baz--
```

My problem is that I can not figure out how to convert that to Filemaker cURL friendly language and pass it as $curlOptions variable so the call to POST can be completed correctly. I have managed to upload the file without metadata, but what I would like to achieve is to make the POST as a multipart. My $curlOptions is sets as follows:

**NOTES**

1. Content-Length is set as 119 because that is the length I got when I run the POST in Postman without an issue
2. Variable $metadata is a json = {"mimeType":"image/jpeg","name":"file.jpeg"}

**My $curlOptions variable is set as follow:**

```
"-X POST"
& " -H \"Authorization: Bearer "  & API_tokens::access_token & "\""
& " -H \"Content-Length: 119\""
& " -H \"Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz\""
& " --foo_bar_baz Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
& " --data-binary @$metadata"
& " --foo_bar_baz Content-Type: image/jpeg"
& " --data-binary @$file"
& " --foo_bar_baz--"
```

I am pretty sure I am not handling the body correctly inside the boundary...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Luis

**EDITED to previous code**

```
"-X POST"
& " -H \"Authorization: Bearer "  & API_tokens::access_token & "\""
& " -H \"Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz\""
& " -H \"Content-Length: 119\"" & Char(13)&Char(10)& Char(13)&Char(10)


& "--data-binary \"--foo_bar_baz" & Char(13)&Char(10) &
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" & Char(13)&Char(10) &
"--data-binary @$metadata" & Char(13)&Char(10) & Char(13)&Char(10) &
"--foo_bar_baz" & Char(13)&Char(10)
& "Content-Type: image/jpeg" & Char(13)&Char(10) & Char(13)&Char(10)
& "--data-binary @$file\"" & Char(13)&Char(10)
& "--foo_bar_baz--"
```

This way it matches how the call looks on google api documenation, but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of FileMaker is low, but your $curlOptions are not including the newline character after the boundaries.  That might be it.  I know FileMaker has a special char allowing you to specify a newline.  You can see from your included documentation reference that there are blank lines at certain points relative to the boundary.

Comment: Hi Paul, many thanks for your input. I had previously found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383474/multipart-mixed-http-request-not-working-using-filemaker-16-curl where @Mata Big user did something similar for another api, in his case only one data on the boundary and advises to add char(10)&char(13) at the end of each line, I did that, but sitll get many errors, which can be malform multipart body, or invalid multipart body with 0 mime, or missing end boundary in multipar body... I have edited my first post to show the code as it is now...but still not working

Comment: What is the error you get?  You've mentioned it's not working, but specifically what are you receiving?